# Hiding divs based on Jquery eq

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

With JavaScript or Jquery, I want to hide the divs that have the content "(want to get rid of this div)" inside of them. So targeting the fourth div inside the first list item, and the fourth div inside the third list item. Below is my code. Thank you for the help!!

```
<ul id="category-nav-list" class="list-unstyled no-margin">   
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu menu l1">
                    <div class="department-flyout-categories row">
                        <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test (want to get rid of this column)
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     </li>
                     <li class="dropdown-submenu menu l1">
                    <div class="department-flyout-categories row">
                        <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     </li>
                     <li class="dropdown-submenu menu l1">
                    <div class="department-flyout-categories row">
                        <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test (want to get rid of this column)
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     </li>
                     </ul>
```

What I am working towards:

```
$('something something something .department-flyout-categories .menu-column').eq(4).hide();
```

Comment: Have you tried `$('.menu-column').eq(3).hide()`? The index starts at 0, so the fourth element is actually 3. Also, when do you want these elements to be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

i would just give those a class name and hide it that way. Not sure exactly how you need this to be used.

Comment: Hi amber, I actually do not have access to this code.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? You said you wanted the divs hidden inside of the first item (zero index) and third item (second index), so I assumed this pattern would repeat and you'd choose even indexed elements. I also used `nth-child` instead of `eq`. Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrxa2j9k/) also.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".department-flyout-categories:even .menu-column:nth-child(4)").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="category-nav-list" class="list-unstyled no-margin">   
                    <li class="dropdown-submenu menu l1">
                    <div class="department-flyout-categories row">
                        <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test (want to get rid of this column)
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     </li>
                     <li class="dropdown-submenu menu l1">
                    <div class="department-flyout-categories row">
                        <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     </li>
                     <li class="dropdown-submenu menu l1">
                    <div class="department-flyout-categories row">
                        <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test
                         </div>
                         <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                                test (want to get rid of this column)
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     </li>
                     </ul>
```

Comment: Hi Nick, it would actually be random, not even...sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @dilonv2 No problem. Is there a way to determine which `department-flyout-categories` classes you need to delete from, or is it based on the contents of the div?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of:

- [:even](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/): in your case this will let you select the first and last **department-flyout-categories**
- [:last-child](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) in order to select the last child of each **department-flyout-categories**

```js
$('#category-nav-list .dropdown-submenu div:even div:last-child').hide();

$('#category-nav-list .dropdown-submenu div:even div:last-child').each(function(idx, ele) {
    console.log(idx + ':  ' + ele.textContent.trim())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="category-nav-list" class="list-unstyled no-margin">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu menu l1">
        <div class="department-flyout-categories row">
            <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                test (want to get rid of this column)
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu menu l1">
        <div class="department-flyout-categories row">
            <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu menu l1">
        <div class="department-flyout-categories row">
            <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="menu-column col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                test (want to get rid of this column)
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi @gaetanoM, it would actually be random, not even...sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Select all divs with the same class (you can create an unique class for the divs like .MyAwesomeDivs or use the ones you have), iterate through them, ask if they have your string inside and if true delete.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5zr7sxmz/1/

```
$('.menu-column.col-sm-4.col-md-3').each(function(i, obj) {
   if($(this).html().indexOf("want to get rid of this column") >= 0)
   {
       $(this).hide();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.menu-column.col-sm-4.col-md-3').each(function(i, obj) {
if($(this).html().indexOf("want to get rid of this column") >= 0)
{
   $(this).hide();
}
});
```

@FerDeath had the code I was looking for...thank you all.